How can I change the color of the file name and line number in pytest output?

I have the above output from pytest to make it easier to find info of interest. One thing I'd like to do is make he file name and line number pop out in a different color.
I have a custom log_helper module I'm using:
import logging
import os
import pprint

# Initialize the logger at the module level, so it's only created once
logger = logging.getLogger('debug_logger')

# Set up the logger only if it hasn't been set up already
if not logger.handlers:
    log_level = os.environ.get('LOG_LEVEL', 'WARNING').upper()
    logger.setLevel(getattr(logging, log_level, logging.WARNING))

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s: %(message)s')
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

class RelativePathFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, *args, base_path=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Define the base path (in your case ~/python)
        self.base_path = base_path if base_path else os.path.expanduser('~/python')
    
    def format(self, record):
        # Modify the pathname to be relative to the base path
        if record.pathname.startswith(self.base_path):
            record.pathname = os.path.relpath(record.pathname, self.base_path)
        return super().format(record)

# Setup logger using the custom formatter
def get_logger(name='debug_logger'):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)

    # Remove existing handlers to avoid conflicts
    if logger.hasHandlers():
        logger.handlers.clear()

    log_level = os.environ.get('LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG').upper()
    logger.setLevel(getattr(logging, log_level, logging.DEBUG))

    # Apply custom formatter
    formatter = RelativePathFormatter(
        '%(levelname)-8s %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d - %(message)s',
        base_path=os.path.expanduser('~/python')
    )

    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    return logger

# Debug print function that respects log level and logs caller info
def d(data, depth=None):
    """
    Debug print function that logs data in DEBUG mode with optional depth control for complex data structures.
    Shows the correct file and line number of the caller, not log_helper.py.
    
    :param data: The data to log (complex or simple).
    :param depth: Optional depth to limit the structure's representation, defaults to None.
    """
    logger = get_logger()  # Get the global logger
    
    # Bail out immediately if the logger is not in DEBUG mode
    if not logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
        return
    
    # Format the data for debug output
    formatted_data = pprint.pformat(data, depth=depth)
    
    # Check if the formatted data has multiple lines
    if "\n" in formatted_data:
        # Add a newline before the data if it spans multiple lines
        formatted_data = "\n" + formatted_data

    # Adjust the stack level so the logger reports the caller's file and line number
    logger.debug(formatted_data, stacklevel=2)

I'm also using a pytest.ini file:
[pytest]
# Include numbered files as test files
python_files = test_*.py *_test.py [0-9]*-*.py 00-*_test
log_cli_format = %(levelname)-8s %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d - %(message)s 

Finally, I have this conftest.py file:
# File: ~/python/tests/conftest.py

import time
from pathlib import Path
from collections import defaultdict

import pytest

# ANSI color codes
CYAN = '\033[96m'
YELLOW = '\033[93m'
GREEN = '\033[92m'
RED = '\033[91m'
RESET = '\033[0m'

test_results = {}
test_structure = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
start_time = None

import pytest  # Make sure pytest is imported
import logging

@pytest.hookimpl(trylast=True)
def pytest_configure(config):
    logging_plugin = config.pluginmanager.get_plugin("logging-plugin")

    # Change color on existing log level
    logging_plugin.log_cli_handler.formatter.add_color_level(logging.DEBUG, "blue")
    logging_plugin.log_cli_handler.formatter.add_color_level(logging.INFO, "cyan")

def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    global start_time
    start_time = time.time()

def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    # for item in items:
    #     path = Path(item.fspath).relative_to(Path(session.config.rootdir))
    #     dir_path = path.parent
    #     file_name = path.name
    #     test_structure[dir_path][file_name].append(item)

    # Sort items based on their location in the file
    items.sort(key=lambda x: x.location[1])

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    result = outcome.get_result()
    
    if result.when == 'call':
        test_results[item.nodeid] = result.outcome

def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    global start_time
    duration = time.time() - start_time

    verbosity = session.config.option.verbose

    if verbosity > 1:
        print("\n")
        for dir_path in sorted(test_structure.keys()):
            print(f"\n{CYAN}{dir_path}{RESET}")
            for file_name in sorted(test_structure[dir_path].keys()):
                print(f"  {YELLOW}{file_name}{RESET}")
                for item in test_structure[dir_path][file_name]:
                    result = test_results.get(item.nodeid, "UNKNOWN")
                    if result == "passed":
                        color = GREEN
                    elif result == "failed":
                        color = RED
                    else:
                        color = YELLOW
                    indent = "    "
                    if "::" in item.name:
                        class_name, test_name = item.name.split("::")
                        print(f"    {class_name}")
                        indent = "      "
                    else:
                        test_name = item.name
                    print(f"{indent}{test_name} {color}{result.upper()}{RESET}")
    
    # Print summary
    passed = sum(1 for result in test_results.values() if result == "passed")
    failed = sum(1 for result in test_results.values() if result == "failed")
    total = len(test_results)
    print(f"\n{GREEN if failed == 0 else RED}=== {passed} passed, {failed} failed, {total} total in {duration:.2f}s ==={RESET}\n")

def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter, exitstatus, config):
    # Completely override the default summary
    pass

I've tried a few different approaches but haven't gotten anywhere.

isn't that for windows? i'm on mac.

@mehdiahmadi I have color codes working. the problem is I don't know where to put them so they actually change the text and aren't overriddent by pytest.

You could use neologger that provides methods to remark logs, or you can set up a template and even apply styles like italic or bold.
First, install the neologger package:
pip install neologger

import the librares NeoLogger for the logger, and Templates for custom templates:
from neologger import NeoLogger
from neologger.core import Template

Then, in your code, add an object in this way:
neologger = NeoLogger("main.py")

Then, you can display logs by calling:
neologger.log_this("Any Log.")

Or add labels by using any of the following methods:
neologger.log_this_ok("Function completed Ok.")
neologger.log_this_warning("Data was sent uncompleted")
neologger.log_this_completed("Data collection stage completed.")
neologger.log_this_success("Request has been completed successfuly")
neologger.log_this_error("Something went wrong!")

You can also use a predefined template by setting it up with (This template is applied to log_this method only:
neologger.set_template(Template.BASE)

For more details on how to implement it follow this link: NeoLogger
And the PiPy page here: enter link description here
Hope it helps.

Please add the code snippets as part of your answer instead of adding links to images with code.

You're right @GaneshTata, I have updated my answer.
